# How to remove the Notification Part from GNOME TOP BAR in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, notification

Ubuntu 20.04 GDM Login Screen
[image]

Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop Screen
[image]

How to remove Notification Part from GNOME TOP BAR in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop...

Compare the Images for Clarity...

Please note that I don't need any notification in any case, I don't suffer If I miss typical notifications also..

So the question is How to remove the Notification part as shown in the Images from Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop ...

Please note that I have gone through this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/ and it is not suitable for my requirement.. I would like to just trying to remove the notification part/area leaving all the top bar elements as it is..